# Given a flow network and a max flow f on it, Determine whether there are at least 4 different max flows

Tags: max-flow

I'm having trouble solving this one and would really appreciate any help. thank you in advance!

so, the problem is:

given a flow network with integer capacities on the edges and a max flow f on that network, I need to write an algorithm (efficient one) that determine whether there are at least 4 more different max flows on that given network.

I have seen people suggesting to check for cycles in the residual network. so if there is a cycle, the max flow is not unique, hence, there is another max flow "f2" and than we can choose every 0 < x < 1 and set infinite max flows such as (1-x)*(|f|) + x*|f2|.but, I cant seem to understand why the cycles in the residual network means that the max flow is not unique and also have a really hard time proving the second part is legal. (the infinite max flows)

thanks again!

Comment: still haven't figured it out. would really appreciate any help. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea with the cycles seems correct. A network *N* has multiple distinct max flows **if and only if** the residual graph of the max flow contains a cycle. If there is more than one max flow there are infinitely many.

If there is a cycle in the residual graph we can augment the flow along that cycle obtaining a different flow. More precisely, let *C* be a cycle in the residual graph of a max flow. Let *d* > 0 denote the smallest residual capacity of an edge of cycle *C*. We can augment the flow on cycle *C* by any amount in the interval [0, *d*] each time obtaining a different max flow (so there are indeed infinitely many max flows, to get four you can augment the flow along cycle *C* by four arbitrary, distinct values from the interval).

We still have to prove that if there are multiple different maximum flows in a network there will indeed always be a cycle in the residual network of any max flow on that network. Doing that in a mathematically rigorous way can be a bit cumbersome, but the main idea is the following: take two distinct max flows *F1* and *F2* and compute the difference between them (i.e. for every edge *e* compute *F1(e) - F2(e)*). Consider the edges where the difference is non-zero. Those edges will all be present in the residual graph of flow *F1* (if the sign of the difference is negative the edge in the direction of flow won't be saturated, if the sign is positive the reverse direction will be present). The conservation of flow constraints at each vertex guarantee that those edges will always form a cycle. For an intuitive understanding you can visualize this drawing both the two flows *F1* and *F2* on the same network in two different colors. You will see that the edges where the flows differ always form cycles. Obviously the flows intersect (at least at source and sink) and from some intersections you will have a path where one flow is greater on one edge and a path where the other flow is greater on another edge. Those two paths must intersect again somewhere deeper in the network (at the latest at the sink but it could also be before), and therefore form a cycle.

Using this, the most efficient algorithm I can think of would be:

1. Compute the residual graph
2. Use DFS to check if there is a cycle in the residual graph (you will probably have to run the DFS multiple times since the residual graph consists of multiple components separated by min cuts)
3. If you have to, generate four different max flows augmenting the flow along the found cycle by different amounts

This would be linear both in the number of vertices and edges